# iphdr type casting giving me error

Tags: linux-kernel, netfilter

I'm trying to print TCP address but I'm getting "Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" error. I think `iphdr` typecasting is not working. How do I fix this issue?

```c
unsigned int hook_func(unsigned int hooknum,
                   struct sk_buff *skb,
                   const struct net_device *in,
                   const struct net_device *out,
                   int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *))
{

   struct iphdr *ip_header;       // ip header struct

   if (!skb)
      return NF_ACCEPT;

   ip_header = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb); /* I think this is not working */

   printk("addr : %lu.\n",ip_header->saddr);
   return NF_ACCEPT;          
}

int init_module()
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "initialize kernel module\n");
    /* Fill in our hook structure */
    nfho.hook = hook_func;         /* Handler function */
    nfho.hooknum  = NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING; /* First hook for IPv4 */
    nfho.pf       = PF_INET;
    nfho.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;   /* Make our function first */

    nf_register_hook(&nfho);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no pointer dereferencing in the line you point. Probably, compiler points to the next line(`printk`), where you extract field `saddr` of variable `ip_header`. For dereferece type `struct iphdr` you need `#include <linux/ip.h>`

Comment: Yep I knew complier was pointing to printk line because there's no saddr attribute. Hence, my conclusion of type casting not working. But your are right, it's because I did not include ip.h header file. Thank you so much! P.S could you create your comment as a post? If anybody runs into same problem, they can use it as a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dereferece pointer of type `struct iphdr` you need

```
#include <linux/ip.h>
```

(Actually, this type is defined in `include/uapi/linux/ip.h`, but usually headers under `uapi/` are included via other ones.)